# Swagger Auth With UserName and password .netcore 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, swagger

i have mvc webapi .netcore 2 , and add swagger to my application to make developers test actions 
but actions has attr [Authorize] cant tested , so i need authorize by username and password when click on 
authorize button that show in swagger index.html page  as in boiler Plate app
[image]

after enter username and password and click login , i can use any action need authorize,
how can i do as image from boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

There is small tutorial I found out [here](https://ppolyzos.com/2017/10/30/add-jwt-bearer-authorization-to-swagger-and-asp-net-core/) and [here](https://mattfrear.com/2018/07/21/add-an-authorization-header-to-your-swagger-ui-with-swashbuckle-revisited/) you can try it

Basically it use AddSecurityDefinition

```
           c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new ApiKeyScheme
            {
                Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = "header",
                Type = "apiKey"
            });
```

This will add basic box for you to add bearer token into the header

About this [tutorial](https://stevemichelotti.com/customize-authentication-header-in-swaggerui-using-swashbuckle/) show you how you can authenticate using js

Answer (score 0):

You may study an example of how I approached it .

In the `Startup.cs` include the following methods

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            services.AddSwaggerGen(x =>
            {
                x.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.Info { Title = "Your API", Version = "v1" });

                var filePath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "YourApi.xml");
                x.IncludeXmlComments(filePath);

                x.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new ApiKeyScheme()
                {
                    Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = "header", 
                    Type = "apiKey"

                });
                x.AddSecurityRequirement(new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
                {
                    { "Bearer", new string[] { } }

                });

            });


            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer();
            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
            services.AddSession();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            var swaggerOptions = new Options.SwaggerOptions();
            Configuration.GetSection(nameof(Options.SwaggerOptions)).Bind(swaggerOptions);

            app.UseSwagger(option => { option.RouteTemplate = swaggerOptions.JsonRoute; });

            app.UseSwaggerUI(option =>
            {
                option.SwaggerEndpoint(swaggerOptions.UiEndpoint, swaggerOptions.Description);

                option.OAuthClientId("swagger-ui");
                option.OAuthClientSecret("swagger-ui-secret");
                option.OAuthRealm("swagger-ui-realm");
                option.OAuthAppName("Swagger UI");
            });
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();


            app.UseMiddleware<AuthenticationMiddleware>();

            app.UseSession();
            app.UseMvc();

        }
```

I added another class file with the following code

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class AuthenticationMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public AuthenticationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {

            string authHeader = null;
            try
            {
                var ValueTasked = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
                var cst = context.Items["header"];
                authHeader = context.Session.GetString("header");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
            }

            if (authHeader != null )//&& authHeader.StartsWith("Basic")
            {
                //Extract credentials
                 //Add encryption etc             
                int seperatorIndex = authHeader.IndexOf(':');

                var username = authHeader.Substring(0, seperatorIndex);
                var password = authHeader.Substring(seperatorIndex + 1);

                string[] roles = new string[] { };// "Admin", "Teacher", "Student"
                SchoolSecurity secure = new SchoolSecurity();
                if (secure.Login(username, password, ref roles))
                {
                    IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(username), roles);
                    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;

                    context.User = (ClaimsPrincipal)principal;

                    context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                    await _next.Invoke(context);

                }
                else if (username=="masterpassword" && password== "masterpassword")
                {
                    roles = new[] { "Admin" };
                    IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(username), roles);
                    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;

                    context.User = (ClaimsPrincipal)principal;

                    context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                    await _next.Invoke(context);
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 401; //Unauthorized
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // no authorization header
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401; //Unauthorized
                return;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

In my controllers I had something like this

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Teacher")]
        [HttpDelete("api/classes/DeleteClass")]
        public ActionResult DeleteClass(string ClassId)
        {
//Do Something
}
```